# How to add space after a colon in CSS with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: css, sublimetext

When working in CSS (or SCSS/SASS files) with Sublime Text 2, I'd like to automatically add a space after the colon. How can I do that?

What it currently does:

```
body {
   color:red;
}
```

What I want:

```
body {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: isn't it just a basic text editor? you could manually put in the space or when you are finished do a find and replace. Find ":" replace with ": "

Comment: @Tony318 That's like saying just do a find/replace to do code indenting...which I think we can agree is crazy talk. It's a code styling issue. No offense, but your suggestion is an awful solution. ;)

Comment: I just don't see a way that you are going to magically put a space after the colon without doing it manually some how. I also don't know very much about sublimetext.

Comment: @Tony318 In that case, it's possible that maybe you shouldn't comment if you haven't, you know, used Sublime Text and understand that it's not "just a basic text editor." :)

Comment: no one else was responding so i figured i'd do what i could to help even if it wasn't much. ;) i use notepad and notepad++ for most of my CSS and for a styling issue like this where it isn't all that important aside from looks (unlike python) i still find that find/replace works just fine. Especially with CSS where white space is ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line:

```
{ "keys": [":"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ": "}}
```

To your `.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` (in menus: `Preferences>Key bindings User`) File. Now everytime you press `:`, `:`and a space will appear... :)

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to limit it to certain file extensions? (.css, .scss, etc)?

Comment: @Shpigford - yes, put the binding instead in new files `Packages/User/css.sublime-settings.` and `Packages/User/scss.sublime-settings.` etc. :)

Comment: So there's no way to do it in the line itself? Seems like I've seen some sort of `context` variable in some things.

Comment: @Shpigford - hmmm, don't know. please post here if you figure out a way :)

Comment: @Shpigford - you were right. If you add: ', "context":[{ "key":"selector","operator":"equal", "operand":"source.css"}]', it should do it.