# How to remove extra space after a colon in CSS with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: css, macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When auto-complete is triggered for a CSS style, Sublime by default adds a space after colon like so:

```
position: relative;
```

How do I remove this space?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the space ?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Because I like it without :)

Comment: Can you put your source code in here or anywhere else so we can see it?

Comment: I don't think his code is going to tell us much.  This is coming at it from the opposite direction, but it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931866/how-to-add-space-after-a-colon-in-css-with-sublime-text-2

Comment: I tried that, no luck. Thanks though :(

Comment: This might not be a useful comment, but my Sublime (v2.0.1) for Mac doesn't even auto-complete a colon, so if I type `position` it completes the property, but doesn't add a colon or space. What OS are you on? I know my Linux Sublime exhibits slightly different behaviors.

Comment: I actually have the exact same question. +1.

Comment: I realized that my auto-complete doesn't include colons when I'm working in SASS files. When I'm in pure CSS files, they do show up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did some more digging and would like to suggest an alternate solution.

1. Open `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/CSS/css_completions.py` in Sublime.
2. On line 190, remove the space after the colon:

   ```
   l.append((p, p + ": "))
   ```

The only caveat I can think of is that this might get overwritten when you update Sublime, but this seemed to work great without installing an extra package.

Comment: Awesome! This works! Hopefully it won't get overwritten when the app is updated.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and this solved it. Also, I tried updating to version 2.01 of Sublime, and it didn't overwrite the change for me. Thanks! +1.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I submitted a different solution below, but would like to leave this here in case ppl are interested in Emmet which still looks pretty neat.

I'd like to offer up a somewhat tested solution :P I got it to replace my `:<space>` with a `:)`.

- Install the Emmet package for Sublime Text 2: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime (easiest way is via the Package Manager)

> This seems like a pretty popular plugin. I would scan the feature set first though because it looks like it'll add a bunch of shortcuts you might not want.

- Check out the documentation on customization: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/
- Search the page for `css.valueSeparator` -- This is the field you want to change. It defaults to `:<space>`
  – There are instructions for editing the package's preferences here: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/

> I think I might actually keep/try this package myself. I hope it gives you what you're looking for.

**Edit:**
I found the emmet instructions somewhat vague. Specifically, in Sublime Text 2 go to:

`Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings - User` and enter your override preferences there in JSON format. Handily, you can cut and paste template code from `Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings - Default` (but leave that file alone as it'll be overwritten when the package is next updated).

Comment: Thank you for adding details about the preferences :)

Comment: For emmet:
Prefecenses > Package Setting > Emmet > Settings-User inside paste this code.
{
"preferences": {
"css.valueSeparator": ":"
}
}

Comment: for emmet 3, add this to your prefs:

{ "config": { "stylesheet":{ "options":{ "stylesheet.between":":", "stylesheet.after":"; " } } } }

Answer (score 0):

Extra answer to add that if you're working in Sass or SCSS files, you'll need to edit the snippets one-by-one in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Sass/Snippets to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Emmet package, the following solution should work with Sublime Text 3 too:

Open: Sublime Text 3 > Package Setting > Emmet > Settings-User and paste

```
{
    "preferences": {
        "css.valueSeparator": ":",
    },
}
```

Answer (score -9):

Solution for Sublime Text 3:

Installing Pacage control (if not already installed):
Open a console ctrl + `

Insert:

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '2915d1851351e5ee549c20394736b442' + '8bc59f460fa1548d1514676163dafc88'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

Press eneter, check console and restart the program.

Start Pacage control with combination Ctrl + Shift + P
Select "Pacage control: Install Pacage", wait for new window
Select PackageResourceViewer
Select "PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource"
Select CSS
Select css_completions.py

change:

```
.append ((p, p + ":"))
```

on:

```
.append ((p, p + ":"))
```

If you have Emmet Pacage, you also need to do:

In the top menu
Package Setting> Emmet> Settings-User and paste

```
{
    "Preferences": {
        "Css.valueSeparator": ":"
    }
}
```