# How to change css autocomplete style

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

When I type "he" SublimeText2 offers me "height". Good.

However when I confirm I want to have

`height:|;` instead of `height: |` (| indicates the cursor).

Where to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your [Packages folder](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory). Then to the `CSS` folder.  Open `css_completions.py`.

Almost at the bottom, inside of the `on_query_completions` method, there is a line

```
l.append((p, p + ": "))
```

change to:

```
l.append((p, p + ":"))
```

Remove the space after the colon.

### Edit

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> after entering value to get semicolon.

Also, [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/) is worth checking out for nice completions/snippets and more.  However, editing those is another question.

### Edit2

Here's a similar question: [How to remove extra space after a colon in CSS with Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149024/how-to-remove-extra-space-after-a-colon-in-css-with-sublime-text-2)